# get Id instead value of select box onchange

Tags: javascript, html

I Wrote a code to get ID of select instead value on change

```html
<select id="price" class="form-control" name="price">
  <option id="1000" value="monthly">qqq</option>
  <option id="2000" value="quarterly">www</option>
  <option id="3000" value="semi_annually">eee</option>
  <option id="4000" value="annually">rrr</option>
</select>
```

```js
const select = document.getElementById("price");
const priceSelect = select.options[select.selectedIndex];

const onPriceChange = (e) => {
  display.textContent = priceSelect + ' Dollars';
};
```

but I get this error :

```
[object HTMLOptionElement]
```

I Wrote that code and I get error

Comment: hello
please show where you're calling onPriceChange in your code.
also just confirming you want the form key of "price" to store the value of 1000 instead of "monthly", right?

Comment: The "priceSelect" is an object of type HTMLOptionElement   ( cf  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option   ).     ID is in priceSelect.id